# How can I represent a single row from result set as multiple rows?

Tags: sql, mysql

Given for example a currency rates table with these columns (used 3 here, but in my situation there are about 30):

```
  date     | eur | usd | gbp
2010-01-28 | X   | Y   | Z
```

How do I convert it to this one (using row with the latest date):

```
currency | rate
eur      | X
usd      | Y
gbp      | Z
```

I've come up with a query like this:

```
SELECT 'eur' AS currency, eur AS rate FROM rates WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM rates)
UNION
SELECT 'usd' AS currency, usd AS rate FROM rates WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM rates)
UNION
...
```

It's huge and ugly. Are there other solutions ?

Comment: Any particular reason you need it with currency and rate columns instead of a single row?

Comment: Sunds like a badly designed database can you alter the schema?

Comment: Because in this form it can be JOIN-ed with other tables.

Comment: Mark: Yes, probably. Isn't current schema optimal for storage requirements ? (i.e. size of the table)

Comment: if you were to list all the databse problems on SO (and anywhere else for that matter), about 0.005% would be space problems and 99.995% would be performance problems. Just keep in mind that 27% of all statistics are plucked out of people's rear ends :-) The figures may not be right but the reality is: most DB problems are speed, not storage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes the easiest solution (if you want nice-looking queries) is to re-engineer the schema. It may well be that the best solution is to change your table to be:

```
   date    | currency | rate
-----------+----------+-----
2010-01-28 |   eur    |  X
2010-01-28 |   usd    |  Y
2010-01-28 |   gbp    |  Z
```

with suitable indexes on date and currency for performance. That's the way it *should* be in 3NF since the rates depend on each other, violating the 3NF rule:

> Every column must depend on the key, the whole key and nothing but the key, so help me Codd.

(I love that little ditty). Another alternative is to provide a view which does the same thing, then you query the view. It's no less work for the DBMS but *your* query at least looks prettier (the `create view` still looks ugly though).

Or you could just accept the fact that some queries look ugly, document it well, and move on :-)

Comment: That is definitely a better schema, but the rates don't necessarily depend on each other. More likely is that all three are trading rates which won't quite add up to 1 because of the banks' margin.

Comment: Banks tend to have separate buy and sell rates with a (roughly) 2% spread (at least) and that's where they make their profit, but all the systems I've seen lock to an internal "currency" so as to prevent arbitrage. Otherwise, sneaky traders could do eur-usd, usd-gbp and gbp-eur trades for guaranteed profit, zero risk.

Comment: If I change the schema according to your post, updating the rates will require many inserts to the table. So it should be done in a transaction, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, it probably should be done as a single transaction to ensure there's no window where arbitrage could take place. Of course, there are other solutions to prevent this, such as doing it during down-time where no application uses the tables, but I'm a firm believer in a DBMS enforcing it's own rules as much as possible and at the lowest level possible. You can never be certain that other apps will follow the rules (due to either malicious intent or incompetence).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do it in SQL?

This is quite trivial using a programming language.

In PHP:

```
$q = mysql_query("
  SELECT    eur, usd, gbp
  FROM      rates
  ORDER BY  date DESC 
  LIMIT 1
");

$table = false;
if($val = mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $table = array(
    'eur' => $val['eur'],
    'usd' => $val['usd'],
    'gbp' => $val['gbp'],
  );
}
echo "currency | rate\n";
echo "-----------------";
foreach($table as $cur => $rate)
  echo $curr."      | ".$rate."\n";
```

Comment: This is actually what I have now :-) But joining tables/views seem to be a more natural approach for me.